# Concatenation of Int array + string array in python (similar to paste() in R)?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I'm new in the python world, I have been always taking advantage of the vectorized operations of R, so I have a basic question...

I have 2 arrays, 1 with `int` values and the other with `string` ones. I would like to have a pandas series with the concatenation of both like:

```
0      Enterobact
1        Pseudomo
2        Mycobact
3             Bac
4        Streptoc
5    Propionibact
6       Staphyloc
7           Morax
8        Synechoc
9            Gord
Name: fam, dtype: object

0    7275
1    3872
2    3869
3    1521
4    1408
5    1022
6     877
7     765
8     588
9     578
Name: frequency, dtype: int64
```

And I would like to have the following..:

```
Enterobact - 7275
Pseudomo - 3872
Mycobact - 3869
# And so on...
```

Which should be the proper way to solve this problem in python? Not the way adapted for R users. Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: Are you sure you have two arrays or do you have two dataframe columns that you want to combine?

Comment: @JANO I have extracted data from 2 columns of a dataframe. I have 2 series. Sorry for the terminology...

Comment: It's not about terminology. I only think it is more efficient to directly combine two columns instead of creating arrays and then combining them.

Comment: @JANO oh, ok! I just operated them outside because I wanted to use this combined list for labels in a legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure in what format you actually need the result but I will give you two methods. First of all, I assume that your data is stored in two variables:

```
print(fam_column)
print(freq_column)
```

Output of the two vars is exactly what you have:

```
0      Enterobact
1        Pseudomo
2        Mycobact
3             Bac
4        Streptoc
5    Propionibact
6       Staphyloc
7           Morax
8        Synechoc
9            Gord

Name: fam, dtype: object
0    7275
1    3872
2    3869
3    1521
4    1408
5    1022
6     877
7     765
8     588
9     578
Name: frequency, dtype: int64
```

So, the first method makes use of the fact that these lists are dataframe columns and we can use operations from `pandas`. The code simply concatenates the rows together as string and in the middle is `-`:

```
result = fam_column + ' - ' + freq_column.astype(str)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
0      Enterobact - 7275
1        Pseudomo - 3872
2        Mycobact - 3869
3             Bac - 1521
4        Streptoc - 1408
5    Propionibact - 1022
6        Staphyloc - 877
7            Morax - 765
8         Synechoc - 588
9             Gord - 578
dtype: object
```

In your question, you mentioned that you want to combine two arrays (in python lists), therefore I created a second method. This one is not preferred as using the existing dataframes is much simpler. This method converts your columns into two lists and then combines them in a generator to the desired form.

```
list_fam = list(df1['fam'])
list_frequency = list(df2['frequency'])

result = [x + ' - ' + str(y) for x, y in zip(list_fam,list_frequency)]
print(result)
```

The output is the following:

```
['Enterobact - 7275', 'Pseudomo - 3872', 'Mycobact - 3869', 'Bac - 1521', 'Streptoc - 1408', 'Propionibact - 1022', 'Staphyloc - 877', 'Morax - 765', 'Synechoc - 588', 'Gord - 578']
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for! I could do it just by iterating in the range of both lists but the use of `zip` is definitely better. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help!